# Currying - How is returned function called with a second argument in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, currying

How does the second argument get called in liftf(add)(1)?

```
function add (first, second) {
    return first + second;
}

function liftf (binary) {
    return function (first) {
        return function (second) {
            return binary(first, second);
        };
    };
}

var inc = liftf(add)(1);
```

I understand how lift(add) is called and stored.

I am confused on how a function is returned but then called with (1).

I first explored if it operated on the same principle of an IIFE but it doesn't seem to. IFFE's would be (function() {}()) vs funciton() {}().

The 'chained' function arguments confuse me and I want to understand what's going on.

Thanks!

Comment: That's what `()` after a value does--calls it.

Comment: `add = first`, `1 = second`. If you understand that `liftf(add)` is a function, then you should understand that calling that function with `1` is no miracle, because that is what functions are for: to be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an expression evaluates to a function, then that function can be invoked with parentheses and the list of arguments.

Since the expression `liftf(add)` returns a function, you call the returned function with the parameter `1` in parentheses: `liftf(add)(1)`

Another way to look at it is if you set `liftf(add)` to a variable, then you could call the function stored in that variable:

```
var additionFunc = liftf(add) // Stores the new function in additionFunc
var result = additionFunc(1) // Evaluates the new function
```

Let's also look at [IIFEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression). Suppose we have one like this:

```
(function(x) {return x + 1})(5)
```

The `(function() { /* ... */ })` expression evaluates to a function, which is then evaluated by the parentheses and argument `(5)`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at a simpler example of currying:

```
function add(x) {
    return function (y) {
        return x + y;
    };
}
```

If you called it with only one argument, like so:

```
add(2);
```

It would expand to:

```
function (y) {
    return 2 + y;
}
```

Which would expect a `y` argument (if you called it). You could run that like this:

```
function (y) {
    return 2 + y;
}(5)
```

Or more succintcly:

```
add(2)(5);
```

Each function just expands to a new anonymous function when currying, so even though it looks weird, once you expand the code out, it will start to make sense.